# AJAX Get txt file wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to learn AJAX, and do the example listed on W3School, but when I set up node js as server and trying to change DOM of my html, it didn't work.
[image]

This is before I press Button.

[image]

This is after I press Button.

The example lists below:
[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load)

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us the actual code

Comment: do you have a demo_test.txt file?

Comment: 1) Never use W3Schools for anything, see http://w3fools.com 2) Please add your actual code to the question, not images of it 3) if you're running this on your local machine you're probably being stopped by the browser's security as you can't make AJAX requests to the local filesystem. You need to run on a webserver.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Have you actually *read* w3fools lately? Frontpage says: *"W3Schools still has issues but they have at least worked on the primary concern developers had. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience. "*

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan On point #3, OP notes that there's a node.js server involved, and *something* is definitely being loaded into `#div1`

Comment: @GolezTrol W3Schools could start paying people to use it and I would still advise people not to. They are scheisters who tried to pass themselves off for years as being affiliated with the W3C while spreading misleading, and sometimes completely wrong, information. There are far better websites available for the beginner, such as http://codecademy.com

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's okay to have that opinion and I can't say I disagree completely. I'm just saying that w3fools is a lot milder on the subject now, so maybe you shouldn't use it as a reference to endorse your opinion.

Comment: @Craicerjack yes, I have this txt file in the same folder

Comment: @GuanWang What's the content of the demo_test.txt file?

Comment: @MazzCris<h2>jQuery and AJAX is FUN!!!</h2>
<p id="p1">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>

Comment: whats the name of the file your code is in? It looks like you are loading your code into your div.

Comment: Does you application has read permission to "demo_test.txt"? Can you access "host/demo_test.txt" client side?

Comment: Your question is about node.js? or how to read a file.txt?